# How to pass a prop into a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got started with Reactjs and have some trouble getting a demo working. If you are interested I have the whole project [open sourced](https://github.com/houmie/reactjs-demo).

I have a searchBox that contains a SearchForm. Once the user posts the search, SearchResult should show the json from server.

```
React.render(
    <SearchBox url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/search"/>,
    document.getElementById('search-golden-facilities')
);

var SearchBox = React.createClass({
    handleSearchSubmit: function(search_param){
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: search_param,
            success: function(data){
                this.setState({data:data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {data: [{"x": "huh"}]};
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="searchBox">
                SID <SearchForm onSearchSubmit={this.handleSearchSubmit} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var SearchForm = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sid = this.refs.sid.getDOMNode().value.trim();
        if(!sid) {
            return;
        }
        this.props.onSearchSubmit({sid: sid});
        this.refs.sid.getDOMNode().value = '';
        return;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <form className="searchForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Enter SID" ref="sid"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

Where it gets problematic is the SearchResult:

```
React.render(
    <SearchResult data='{"x":"test"}'/>,
    document.getElementById('result-golden-facilities')
);

var SearchResult = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
       var resultRows = this.props.data.map(function(result){
           return (
                <p>{result.x}</p>
           );
       });
       return (
           <div className="searchResult">
                {resultRows}
           </div>
       );
   }
});
```

I get a javascript error in Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

It seems that `data` is undefined. I don't understand why, as I define it in the initial state.

```
var resultRows = this.props.data.map(function(result){
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wrap your properties with single quote React sends them to component as a string. It's better to use `{`:

```
React.render(
    <SearchResult data={ {"x":"test"} } />,
    document.getElementById('result-golden-facilities')
);
```

or for better readability:

```
var data = { x: 'test' };
React.render(
    <SearchResult data={ data } />,
    document.getElementById('result-golden-facilities')
);
```

Another issue in your code is how you use `.map()`. You are trying to use native javascript map method on object, which doesn't exist. Either you should change your data into array:

```
var data = [{ x: 'test' }];
```

or simply render:

```
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
       return (
           <div className="searchResult">
                {this.props.data.x}
           </div>
       );
   }
});
```